# F# sort by indexes

Tags: f#

Let's say I have two lists:

```
let listOfValues = [100..105]   //can be list of strings or whatever
let indexesToSortBy = [1;2;0;4;5;3]
```

Now I need `listOfValues_sorted`: `102;100;101;105;103;104`

It can be done with `zip` and "conversion" to Tuple:

```
let listOfValues_sorted = listOfValues 
                        |> Seq.zip indexesToSortBy
                        |> Seq.sortBy( fun x-> fst x)
                        |> Seq.iter(fun c ->  printfn "%i" (snd c))
```

But I guess, there is **better solution** for that?

Comment: Note that your example output from `listOfValues_sorted` is `102;100;101;104;105;103`, but the sample code you give will **actually** produce `102;100;101;105;103;104`. I believe the latter is what you actually want, so that's how I answered your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your solution is pretty close. I would do this

```
let listOfValues_sorted = 
    listOfValues 
    |> Seq.zip indexesToSortBy
    |> Seq.sortBy fst
    |> Seq.toList
    |> List.unzip
    |> List.head
```

you can collapse `fun x -> fst x` into simply `fst`. And then `unzip` and get what ever list you want

Comment: Fine.Thnx. Another simplification could be by using list only. But there is a problem with 'not same length' of sequences (Seq is fine with different length??). Question updated -> Lists have same length (original purpose).

Comment: I believe `List.permute` is a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

If `indexesToSortBy` is a complete set of indexes you could simply use:

```fs
indexesToSortBy |> List.map (fun x -> listOfValues |> List.item x )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example sounds precisely what the [`List.permute` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.permute%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) is for:

```
let listOfValues = [100..105]
let indexesToSortBy = [|1;2;0;4;5;3|]  // Note 0-based indexes

listOfValues |> List.permute (fun i -> indexesToSortBy.[i])
// Result: [102; 100; 101; 105; 103; 104]
```

Two things: First, I made `indexesToSortBy` an array since I'll be looking up a value inside it N times, and doing that in a list would lead to O(N^2) run time. Second, `List.permute` expects to be handed a 0-based index into the original list, so I subtracted 1 from all the indexes in your original `indexToSortBy` list. With these two changes, this produces exactly the same ordering as the `let listOfValues_sorted = ...` example in your question.